# sql display in a particular format

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to display the output in a particular format.
[1st, 2nd, 3rd are the product IDs and 4th row is a product itself and is a master id too for 1st, 2nd, 3rd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slFzL.jpg)

Format I want to display in
[Master status exists in the status column and does not exist independently in any separate column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giHuK.jpg)

I can use a subquery to find the data for a specific status, but cannot use it to display the value

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL can provide the desired output

```
SELECT      P1.PID AS PRODUCT_ID, 
            P1.STATUS AS PRODUCT_STATUS, 
            P2.PID AS MASTER_ID,
            P2.STATUS AS MASTER_STATUS 
FROM        PRODUCTS AS P1 
INNER JOIN  PRODUCTS AS P2 
ON          P1.MASTER = P2.PID
```

Output

```
PRODUCT_ID  PRODUCT_STATUS      MASTER_ID   MASTER_STATUS
----------------------------------------------------------
1234        Active              7473        Active
3457        Active              7473        Active
3685        Disabled            7473        Active
```